# How i can find Build variants in Intelij Idea as in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, build-variant

How I can find Build variants for `Intelij Idea` as in `Android Studio`?

> **IntelliJ Idea:**

[image]

> **Android Studio:**

[image]

Comment: Do you have "Android" bundled plugin enabled and android project opened in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov yep.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the same place in IDEA with Android plugin installed, when active window is the one with Android project.

When I open Android project in IDEA, it's almost indistinguishable from Android Studio. It seems that your IDE failed to recognize your project, or another, non-Android project is in foreground.

[image: Idea]